# FTP put several directories without overwrite?

Tags: linux, ftp, file-transfer, overwrite

I was transferring a few dozen gigs from one PC to another with scp. I got disconnected and double checked and found FTP to be faster (I scp only affected CPU to encrypt)

How do I resume my file transfer? I want to copy all of my files recursing from a root directory and not spend hours overwrite files.

I am using FTP on the command line for Mac Leopard which should be the same as linux

What is the command to put multiple directories without overwriting files (while still recurring) with FTP?

Answer (score 4):

You can only restart a download with ftp not an upload (as far as I know) the native command would be "reget" and the remote server has to support it.

That being said if you have already gotten a partial transfer done with sftp, and wish to continue you may want to look at rsync or rsync over ssh to complete your transfer. I.e rsync -avz . -e "ssh" user@host:/targetdir/

Most of the slowness you experience with scp is related to the encryption and the serial nature of the connection.

Comment: What command can i use to put files via ftp without overwrite?

Comment: +1 for rsync -- that's the way to copy a few dozen gigs